# Android - Fragment - Set attributes for fragment

Tags: android, attributes, fragment

I would like to know if there is a proper way to initiate attributes of a custom Fragment.
It's not recommended to define constructors.

Let's do some example:

```
class MyFrag extends Fragment{
private int id;
private String name;
//no constructors
//oncreateview ...

public void onStart() {
super.onStart();
//I was using callback method before
//setId(callback.getId);
}
public void setId(int id){ this.id=id;}
public void setName(String name){ this.name=name;}
}
```

My question is that I instantiate my fragment, I set attributes through setters, and then I use the fragmentManager to add the fragment.
Is it a good way to acheive setters of attributes?

I came to that question when I was trying to create a LinearLayout composed of several fragments using my pojo's attributes to initialize views states of the fragment.
Callback method would be useless until fragment had an attribute describing its index (to retrieve my pojo in my activity List).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
bundle.putString("message", "From Activity");
fragment.setArguments(bundle);
```

from your calling activity

Comment: I'm using fragmentmanager to add fragment to the LinearLayout, I can't figure out when the Intent will be received then?

Comment: @PacDroid i have edited the code, try the above and if it doesnt work can you post your FragmentManager code

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer. It helps very much, I found the right google resource on it (using viewpager for navigation) at http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html